# Constructor injection with mocked object which has to set mocked value in constructor

Tags: mockito, spring-test

I'm trying to mock a class `FooB`, which has another component `FooA` injected via constructor injection. My problem is, that in constructor `FooB` a value from injected component `FooA` has to be set. My problem I don't know the way how to mock `FooA`. Usually I would do something like in the commented out code in a `@BeforeAll` and mock the value with `Mockito.when`. But at this stage `FooB` is already initialized.

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { FooB.class })
class FooTest {

  @MockBean
  private FooA fooA;

  @Autowired
  private FooB fooB;

  // @BeforeAll
  // void initMocks() {
  //  when(fooA.getFoo()).thenReturn("foo");
  // }
}

@Component
public class FooB {
  private final String foo;

  public FooB(final FooA fooA) {
    this.foo = fooA.getFoo(); // <- how do I get the mocked value in here?
  }
}

@Component
public class FooA {
  private String foo;

  public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
  }

  public void setFoo(final String foo) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code could solve what you are trying to do (Edit : Added both a test case that uses `@SrringBootTest` and without it as well)

## If not using SpringBoot

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {FooB.class, FooTest.TestConfig.class})
class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooB fooB;

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {

        @Bean
        FooA getFooA(){
            FooA fooA = Mockito.mock(FooA.class);
            when(fooA.getFoo()).thenReturn("foo from test");
            return fooA;
        }
        
    }

    @Test
    void testFooB() {
        assertEquals("foo from test", fooB.getFoo());
    }
}
```

## If using SpringBoot

```
@SpringBootTest
class FooTest {

    @Autowired
    private FooB fooB;

    @TestConfiguration
    public static class TestConfig {

        @MockBean
        private FooA fooA;

        @PostConstruct
        void initMocks() {
            when(fooA.getFoo()).thenReturn("foo from test");
        }

    }

    @Test
    void testFooB() {
        assertEquals("foo from test", fooB.getFoo());
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's not a spring boot application

Comment: @user871611 that changes everything. Let me see if i can do something without the spring boot test annotations

Comment: @user871611 Updated the answer, added the other way which uses the same structure as your original question.

Comment: this did the trick. I would never come up with this solution, thanks.